# Domain ovh & personnal web hosting

Tags: .htaccess, dns, cross-domain, hosting

I have my own website at home: `http://[public ip]/website`

I bought a domain on ovh.

I try a redirect but when I go to my domain I see my own public ip. How can I stay on url like

```
http://{ovh domain}
```

I try to follow some tutorial but I found nothing.

Like use the `.htaccess` file with rewrite module.

Thanks for all.

---

### EDIT :

Page 
Manager OVH > Website hosting > Domains & DNS > DNS Zone(Advanced mode)

In Section
Manage pointing entry

Select
A Type

Then ? I don't really understand what does the manager try to ask me ? Create a subdomain ?

---

### EDIT 2 :

At this time i'm trying this :

www.{ovhdomain}.com | A | xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Is it correct ? How many time it need to be active ?

---

### EDIT 3:

Ok, now i have my domain instead of my public ip. but it remains the name of my website behind : on my computer, my ip go to the xamp page, the behinf my project : http://{ip}/{project}

so i get http://{ovh_domain}/{project}

How to make http://{ovh_domain} go to http://{ip}/{project} and not only http://{ip}/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an [A record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) on the domain name to point it to your IP address.